# LINUX: change number of lines/columns that are displayed in a terminal (without X)

Tags: linux, command-line, graphics-card, x-server

I'm using a linux server without X
I want to understand how to change the number of lines/columns I see, like I change resolution in X.. besides.. I should be able to change the resolution somehow, shouldn't I? I mean, I'm still using a monitor even if it's not with an X server..

The graphics card doesn't see any difference between X and simple linux video buffer, right? So there must be a way to set resolution, refresh rate etc..

if you could point me to some guide out there it'd be fine
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to change the *resolution* of the display (which indirectly changes how many characters fit in each row/column), you can change the mode.

The mode of the graphics card can be set via the `vga` boot parameter (assuming you don't use framebuffer), but the value to set it to depends on your graphics card.

To see what values are available add `vga=ask` which will give you a list to choose and test from. If you use grub just append that to the `kernel` line of `/boot/grub/menu.lst` for your kernel. Once you have decided what mode you want, replace `ask` with that code.

For some documentation see e.g. `Documentation/svga.txt` in the kernel source tree.

Comment: thanks.. didn't find the menu.lst file, though..  
I'm on ubuntu server 9.10

Comment: @luca I don't know ubuntu's setup. But you might be able to play with this by adding the `vga` parameter like described e.g. here http://grumpymole.blogspot.com/2007/05/ubuntu-how-to-edit-grub-boot-parameters.html (assuming ubuntu uses grub and their grub version is compatible with that howto).